# How to run a python script in the background of a fullscreen application

Tags: python, windows-10, background-process, lost-focus

Im trying to run a python script that will move files in the background while in a fullscreen game. When the program runs I want it to not tab me out of the game. Im on Windows 10.

I can run the program through a button on my mouse, but when it runs the command prompt is briefly opened and the game unfocuses.

Comment: I don't think there's any other way around it :3

Comment: Creating a new thread or process might help.

Answer (score 0):

Type this command on your cmd:

`start /b python your_script.py`

`/b` switch tells the cmd to start the script in the background.

Comment: I attempted to run your code using a .bat file, but it still focused on command prompt
The code I ran:
`@ECHO OFF
ECHO Attempting to run file in background
cd (path)
start /b python FileMover.py`

Comment: is there maybe a way instead to have the program refocus the game?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on having it possibly open in the background after seeing that it might be impossible or require threading. Instead, I had the code focus on the game when it finished running.

```
def find_window(title):
    return win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)

def bring_to_foreground(hwnd):
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)  # Restore the window if minimized
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)

app_title = "APPLICATION_NAME"
app_window = find_window(app_title)

if app_window:
    bring_to_foreground(app_window)
    print(f"Window '{app_title}' brought to the foreground.")
else:
    print(f"Window '{app_title}' not found.")
```

Replace the application name with the name of the application desired.